# undefined reference to `WinMain@16' error

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-code

Getting error:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

while compiling a simple c program in Virtual Studio Code.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

I have also installed mingw software even i have give the environment variable. Still getting this error.

Comment: You appear to be trying to create a console application, but I think you told the compiler to create a windowed application (because I think that requires providing a `WinMain` function). Please show the command you are using to compile the application.

Comment: Also, please fix the tags so that only the language you are using is included. (Remove whichever of C or C++ isn't applicable.)

Comment: okay buddy and where to find command that i am using to compile the application

Answer (score 1):

You have created an application with type of `Windows Application`. Create a `Console Application` or change type of current application to console one.

Comment: How to do that? @Afshin

Comment: @itzPrateek you can check here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-a-standard-cpp-program-cpp?view=vs-2019].