# bookshop inventary project in C++ language

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

right now I am making a hands on project on bookshop inventory by using C++ program in Visual Studio Code.

PROBLEM STATEMENT OF THE PROJECT:
A book shop maintains the inventory of books that are being sold at the shop. The list
includes details such as author, title, price, publisher and stock position. Whenever a
customer wants a book, the sales person inputs the title and author and the system
searches the list and displays whether it is available or not.
If it is not, an appropriate message is displayed. If it is, then the system displays the book details and requests for the number of copies required.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

 class book
  {
    private:
    char *author, *title, *publisher;
    float *price;
    int *stock;

  public:
    book()
   {
    author = new char[20];
    title = new char[20];
    publisher = new char[20];
    price = new float;
    stock = new int;
   }
    void feeddata();
    void editdata();
    void showdata();
    int search(char[], char[]);
    void buybook();
    };

    void book::feeddata()
  {
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\nEnter Author Name: ";
    cin.getline(author, 20);
    cout << "Enter Title Name: ";
    cin.getline(title, 20);
    cout << "Enter Publisher Name: ";
    cin.getline(publisher, 20);
    cout << "Enter Price: ";
    cin >> *price;
    cout << "Enter Stock Position: ";
    cin >> *stock;
  }

    void book::editdata()
  {

   cout << "\nEnter Author Name: ";
   cin.getline(author, 20);
   cout << "Enter Title Name: ";
   cin.getline(title, 20);
   cout << "Enter Publisher Name: ";
   cin.getline(publisher, 20);
   cout << "Enter Price: ";
   cin >> *price;
   cout << "Enter Stock Position: ";
   cin >> *stock;
  }

   void book::showdata()
  {
   cout << "\nAuthor Name: " << author;
   cout << "\nTitle Name: " << title;
   cout << "\nPublisher Name: " << publisher;
   cout << "\nPrice: " << *price;
   cout << "\nStock Position: " << *stock;
  }

    int book::search(char tbuy[20], char abuy[20])
  {
   if (strcmp(tbuy, title) == 0 && strcmp(abuy, author) == 0)
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
  }

    void book::buybook()
  {
    int count;
    cout << "\nEnter Number Of Books to buy: ";
    cin >> count;
    if (count <= *stock)
  {
    *stock = *stock - count;
    cout << "\nBooks Bought Sucessfully";
    cout << "\nAmount: Rs. " << (*price) * count;
  }
  else
    cout << "\nRequired Copies not in Stock";
  }

 int main()
    {
      book *B[20];
      int i = 0, r, t, choice;
      char titlebuy[20], authorbuy[20];
      while (1)
      {
         cout << "\n\n\t\tMENU"
              << "\n1. Entry of New Book"
              << "\n2. Buy Book"
              << "\n3. Search For Book"
              << "\n4. Edit Details Of Book"
              << "\n5. Exit"
              << "\n\nEnter your Choice: ";
         cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        B[i] = new book;
        B[i]->feeddata();
        i++;
        break;

    case 2:
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "\nEnter Title Of Book: ";
        cin.getline(titlebuy, 20);
        cout << "Enter Author Of Book: ";
        cin.getline(authorbuy, 20);
        for (t = 0; t < i; t++)
        {
            if (B[t]->search(titlebuy, authorbuy))
            {
                B[t]->buybook();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (t == 1)
            cout << "\nThis Book is Not in Stock";

        break;
    case 3:
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "\nEnter Title Of Book: ";
        cin.getline(titlebuy, 20);
        cout << "Enter Author Of Book: ";
        cin.getline(authorbuy, 20);

        for (t = 0; t < i; t++)
        {
            if (B[t]->search(titlebuy, authorbuy))
            {
                cout << "\nBook Found Successfully";
                B[t]->showdata();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (t == i)
            cout << "\nThis Book is Not in Stock";
        break;

    case 4:
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "\nEnter Title Of Book: ";
        cin.getline(titlebuy, 20);
        cout << "Enter Author Of Book: ";
        cin.getline(authorbuy, 20);

        for (t = 0; t < i; t++)
        {
            if (B[t]->search(titlebuy, authorbuy))
            {
                cout << "\nBook Found Successfully";
                B[t]->editdata();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (t == i)
            cout << "\nThis Book is Not in Stock";
        break;

    case 5:
        exit(0);
    default:
        cout << "\nInvalid Choice Entered";
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

It is a really important project to me...

In this project when When I am running this code following lines are coming on the terminal..

```
PS D:\C_C++ PROJECTS> cd "d:\C_C++ PROJECTS\" ; if ($?) { g++ b_i.cpp -o b_i } ; if ($?) { .\b_i }
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x39): 
undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If anyone know how to fix it, it is helpful to me....

Comment: Do you have multiple cpp files? I suspect you are getting this error because VSCode only builds the active file by default. I expect your active file does not have int main() and you did not modify your tasks.json to have VSCode use all of your cpp files.

Comment: Your statement of the problem probably can be deleted. Your actual code problem is very common and there are many duplicates.

Comment: Your code compiles fine. You only need to configure your development environment properly. You may check for instance this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw  or search for other locations.

Comment: @drescherjm  No. it is a only one file. in my current file I also have a int main() function.

Comment: I asked because when compiling with mingw I believe if it does not find an int main() it attempts to find WInMain and if that is not found you get a linker error. You will find a lot of duplicates for `undefined reference to WinMain@16`

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587326/palo I have already configured  development environment properly , and it's good.  it is not a undefined reference I have taken it from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw. ..and it's original one.

Comment: Can you add the text of your `tasks.json`?

Comment: WinMain@16? Are you compiling a windows app instead of a console app?

Just a remark, but consider using std::string instead of managing all the memory yourself (author = new char[20]). And strcmp function just become '==' operations. It's also more c++ then 'c' that way.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626397/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-winmain16-referenced-in-function

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm I will add the text of tasks.json.. and let you know about it..it's working or not...

Comment: @ https://stackoverflow.com/users/16649550/pepijn-kramer it's not the duplicate one sir.

Comment: I would say this is certainly related to the many `WinMain@16`  duplicates.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm ok sir. is there any other problem in my code that the compiler is not added to the PATH IN A COMPUTER ENVIRONMENT , like this..is it possible to happen such things..due to that my code is not running.

Comment: You can try adding a `-mconsole` argument to gcc in your `tasks.json` and remove a `-mwindows` if it exists.

Comment: Also before we go on make sure that your `b_i.cpp` file in the "d:\C_C++ PROJECTS\"  folder contains the code that you expect. Use some other editor to look at that file. You  would get this same error if this file is empty.

Comment: Unrelated to your compilation issues, do **not** use `char *` and `new` in your project. Use `std::string` and `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should present a [mre] instead of full programs. Have you tried to reduce the size of your code? What happens if you reduce your code down to `int main() {}`? If you get the same error with this trivial program, there is no need for all the distracting, extra fluff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined reference to \`WinMain@16' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065807/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-error). If not, you'll need to provide some details that will distinguish your question from that one.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).